# DB2 to SQL Server data synchronization

Tags: sql-server, db2

I'm in charge of fixing part of an application that syncs data entities from a DB2 database running on an iSeries to a SQL Server database on Azure.  The application seems to run this synchronization just fine when the iSeries and the SQL Server host are on the same local network.  However, add in the change in latency when the database host is in Azure and this process slows to an unacceptable level.

I'm looking for ideas on how to proceed.  Some additional information:

- Some of our clients might have millions of records in some tables.
- An iSeries platform is not virtualizable/containerizable as far as I know.
- Internet connection speed will vary wildly.  Highly dependent on the client.

The current solution uses an ODBC driver to get data from the iSeries.  I've started looking at taking a different approach as far as retrieving the data including creating API's (doesn't seem to be the best idea for transferring lots of data) or using Azure Data Services, but, those are really pieces to a bigger puzzle.

Edit:  I'm trying to determine what the bottleneck is and how to fix it.  I forgot to add that the IT manager (we only have one person in IT...  we are a small company) has setup a test environment using a local iSeries and an instance of our software in Azure.  He tried analyzing the network traffic using Wireshark and told me we aren't using tons of bandwidth, but, there seems to be alot of TCP "chatter".  His conclusion was we need to consider another way to get the data.  I'm not convinced and that is part of the reason I'm here asking this question.

More details:

- Our application uses data from an ERP system that runs on the iSeries.
- Part of our application is the sync process in question.
- The process has two components: a full data sync and a delta/changes data sync.
- When these processes are run when both the iSeries and our application are on site, the performance isn't great, but, it is acceptable.
- The sync process is written in C# and connects to DB2 using an ODBC driver.
- We do some data manipulation and verification as part of the sync process.  i.e., making sure parent records exist, foreign keys are appropriate, etc.

Comment: Question asks "ideas on how to proceed". But with __what__ ?  Do you plan to identify the bottleneck and try to tune it, or do you plan to redesign?   For either of those , your question has insufficient details.

Comment: You should look at some Change Data Capture product which reads the source transaction logs and applies the corresponding changes to the target. Or develop something similar on your own :)